# Set key dynamically inside map() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

So I know how to set the key dynamically like this:

```
var hashObj = {};
hashObj[someValue] = otherValue;
```

But I haven't seen any answer regarding `map()`:

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var hashObject = list.map(function(someValue) {
    return { someValue: 'blah' };
});

// should return: [ {'a': 'blah'}, {'b': 'blah'}, {'c': 'blah'} ];
```

I know I can do this in a `for` loop and such, but is this not possible in javascript using just `map()`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to get `someValue` to be evaluated as its value. If you use object notation, it will be interpreted literally as string.

You can use a temporary object to achieve what you want:

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var hashObject = list.map(function(someValue) {
    var tmp = {};
    tmp[someValue] = 'blah';
    return tmp;
});
```

Comment: Yes, you cannot create a JS literal object definition that uses a variable name for a property name.  As such, you must declare an object and then assign the property (using the property name in variable) separately as this answer does.

Comment: ES6 Shorthand: `return { [someValue]: 'blah' }`

Answer (score 5):

I know it is really old question, but answer can be helpful for others.

As it has been already said, `Array.prototype.map` is used to get new `array`.

But if you want to get `object` instead of `array` - maybe you should think about using `Array.prototype.reduce` (https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

```
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const hashObject = list.reduce((acc, current) => {
  acc[current] = 'blah';
  return acc;
}, {});

// hashObject equals: {"a":"blah","b":"blah","c":"blah"}
```

And if you want achieve the same result as mentioned in your question, you can use `Array.prototype.map` of course:

```js
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const hashArrayOfObjects = list.map((current) => {
  return {[current]: 'blah'};
});

// hashArrayOfObjects equals: [{"a":"blah"},{"b":"blah"},{"c":"blah"}]
```

You can check how it works on CodePen: https://codepen.io/grygork/pen/PojNrXO

Answer (score 0):

Commonly the 'map()' method is used to get new array from each return value.
In your case, I recommend to use forEach().

```
var list = ['a','b','c'];
var hashObject = {};
list.forEach( function( key ) {
    hashObject[ key ] = 'blah';
});
```

Or use object() of underscore.js library

```
var list = ['a','b','c'];
var hashObject = _.object( list ); // { a: undefined, b: undefined, c: undefined }
hashObject = _.mapObject( hashObject, function( val, key ) {
    return 'blah';
});
```

Then again, Array.prototype.map is only used to get new 'array' not 'object'.